# Removing an undesired object from a clip in Final Cut

Tags: final-cut-pro

I have a screen-cast clip. On a white background, I have an icon which I'd like to cover with a shape or something. In fact, I've tried using a vector shape and it partially does its job. The problem I'm having is that the clip starts with a fade in/out transition and I'd like to "hide" the icon also during those frames. Adding the same transition to the vector shape didn't help, so maybe I'm just using the wrong approach.

How could I hide that icon so that it looks natural also during the transition frames?

Comment: I've personally recorded the video and it's not a logo. It's a placeholder on a blank page, which we originally used to avoid the speaker to write in that specific section. But thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've kept using a vector shape. Just, I've setup two keyframes - one at the beginning of the transition and one at the end - for the "color" property, and used the "Select Color" tool so the colour matches the current background. When needed, I've added extra keyframes. It now looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a "garbage mask" to cut out the desired object on the main frame. Doing that, it will be in place during the transition.

If that does not work for you, then just duplicate the transition for the vector object.

Comment: I've tried this. The problem is that, during the transition, the screen goes from white to black, while the mask goes black to white and you notice it during the transition.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job better accomplished with a compositing program like After Effects (or maybe Motion if that's all you have), and not with your editing program.

Also, here's a tutorial that covers how to deal with some difficult situations in object removal:
http://library.creativecow.net/articles/drozda_jerzy/SimpleObjectRemoval.php

Even if you're not an After Effects user, the approach and techniques used in the tutorial are worth knowing.

Answer (score 1):

Put the clip in question in it's own sequence. Apply the vector shape but not the transitions. Then drag the sequence from your browser window into the preview window, then put it into your original timeline as if it were the original clip. Then apply transitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Final Cut X, make the vector shape and the icon into a composite clip, and then apply the transition to that. That way they're both fade in and out together.